# Product Database Attributes

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

I'm having difficulty setting up a product database for an online web-to-print and product database. Some products will just be static products, some may have sizes and some will have full web-to-print capabilities. The web-to-print products may be as simple as a name tag with one or two attribute ( name / title ) or a brochure with 40 or more attributes and constraints. Any direction in the right way to model this would be greatly appreciated. Currently using MySQL / PHP. Should I consider a NoSQL approach? Thanks in advance.

Comment: So what have you tried to this point, what are your pain points?  Certainly if you have products that might have mutable properties to them a NoSQL approach might make sense.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably recommend having the following tables to achieve what you're looking to do:

- `products` - a general one-row-per-product table with general information common to all products
- `product_attributes` - a list of each product attribute with its name and any other information common to all product attributes
- `product_attribute_assignments` - a table with a column for product with a foreign key to the products table and a column for each attribute assigned to the product with a foreign key to the product_attributes table
- `product_attribute_values` - in case you want to store the values that each user puts in for these attributes, you're going to want some column for the session, a column for the product, a column for the attribute, and a column for the attribute's value for the session.

You should then be able to iterate over each product_attribute_assignments row to prompt for each value, and then store each value in the `product_attribute_values` table if you wish.

Comment: When updating in this scenario, would you just delete all attributes associates with a product / session and re-write them?

Comment: @Bradley that depends on your final structure. Sometimes you'll have to reset all of the attribute other times you'll have a structure that allows to update each attribute independently. You're the designer, have fun.